# react native navigation refresh component problem

Tags: react-native

I'm in category page and when i press any of them, it navigates me to the that categories product list. so far so good. when i go back and press another category i get previous categories product list.

there is my some of code

this is how i navigate to product list

```
render() {
    const {navigation} = this.props.navigation;
    const categories = category.map((item, index) => {
      return (
        <TouchableOpacity
          key={index}
          styles={styles.category}
          onPress={() =>
            navigation.navigate('ProductList', {
              categoryName: item.Menu,
            })
          }>
          <Text> {item.Menu} </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      );
    });

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        {this.state.isData ? (
          <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text style={styles.title}>Category</Text>
            {categories}
          </View>
        ) : (
          <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#0B970B" />
        )}
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

and this is where i go, i can get navigation props ext. but i cant find where the problem is

```
import React,{useState,useEffect} from 'react';
import {
  View,
  ScrollView,
  Text,
  Image,
  StyleSheet,
  Dimensions,
  ActivityIndicator,
} from 'react-native';

const List = ({navigation}) => {
  const [isData, setIsData] = useState(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    getData();
    return null;
  }, []);

  const getData = async () => {
    if (navigation?.route?.params?.categoryName) {
      categoryName = navigation.route.params.categoryName;
      fetch(global.apiPost + global.token, requestOptions)
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((result) => {
          result.forEach((element) => {
            if (element.Menu === categoryName) {
              products.push(element);
            }
          });
          setIsData(true);
          console.log(products, 'products');
          console.log(productsByAccessory, 'productsByAccessory');
          console.log(productsByTravel, 'productsByTravel');
          console.log(productsByBag, 'productsByBag');
        })
        .catch((error) => console.log('error', error));
    }
  };

  return (
    <View style={{flex: 1}}>
      <Text style={styles.title}>{categoryName}</Text>
      {isData ? (
        <View style={{flex: 1}}>
          <View style={styles.itemFounds}>
            <Text>{data.length + ' item founds'}</Text>
          </View>
          <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', flexWrap: 'wrap'}}>
            <Text>
              {productsByAccessory.length} / {productsByTravel.length} /{' '}
              {productsByBag.length} / {products.length} asd
            </Text>
          </View>
        </View>
      ) : (
        <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#0B970B" />
      )}
    </View>
  );
}

export default List
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your `render` method

```
const { navigation } = this.props; // Here was the error
const categories = category.map((item, index) => {
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity
      key={index}
      styles={styles.category}
      onPress={() =>
        navigation.navigate("ProductList", {
          categoryName: item.Menu,
        })
      }
    >
      <Text> {item.Menu} </Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
});

render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        {this.state.isData ? (
          <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text style={styles.title}>Category</Text>
            {categories}
          </View>
        ) : (
          <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#0B970B" />
        )}
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

`render` method should have the `return` statement only. Don't perform any operations inside the `render` method. Now it should work.

Comment: i dont why but i cant get navigation props any other way, its class based component. i changed function component but that didnt worked either

Comment: `components` don't have `navigation` prop. Only `screens` have the `navigation` prop.

Comment: I've edited the answer check once.. 1st line